# loops and inserts PostgreSQL PGADMIN III

Tags: sql, foreach

I'm a total SQL noob. I am trying to create a new record in a table for each of a partial list from another table. I can't get the loop syntax right. Basically, here's pseudocode for what I'm trying to do:

```
FOR EACH item FROM "SCHEMA1".table1.field1 WHERE table1.field2 = 500 OR table1.field2 = 900 LOOP
USE "SCHEMA1".table2
INSERT INTO "SCHEMA1".table2 (column1, column2, column3)
  VALUES (row_number(), table1.field1, "done")
END LOOP;
```

table1 has about 4300 records and I want one field from about 90 specific records copied into another existing table as new records (with additional data). Both tables exist in a single schema but the servers have a dozen or so with duplicate tables and fields.

Thanks for taking the time to educate an old noob.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to get using a call to row_number() function.
 Note that according to documentation of row_number() : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html

> Note that these functions must be invoked using window function
>   syntax; that is an OVER clause is required.

so simple call to row_number() without the OVER (...) clause gives you a syntax error.
Here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS you can find detailed description how to use Windows Functions Calls in postgresql.
Anyway, to select rows from the table, and insert them (after some modification) to another table you can use a single SQL command, for example:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3)
Select row_number() over (order by 1 ),
       table1.field1,
       'done'
FROM table1
WHERE table1.field2 = 500 OR table1.field2 = 900;
```

Here is a simple [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e758b/1)

Here you can find a description of the syntax: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-insert.html

In this query we are using this variant of insert:

```
INSERT INTO table [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
    { query }
```

which executes the *query* (just SELECT xxx FROM yyy etc), and then inserts a result of this query (rows returned by the query) to the *table*.

Comment: Thanks @kordirko, I'll try that when I get a chance. I'm stuck with an old version of postgres and a complex database only accessable from a very crippled GUI program. Creating those 90, mostly identical records would take literally days. I was hoping to use PGADMIN to trim that to hours or minutes, as I have with other, simpler tasks. The row_number() was used because the ID column does not autoincrement and I need unique IDs. Thanks for taking the time.